# PyDev, Python: Error importing OpenCV when debugging

Tags: python, debugging, opencv, pydev

I am having problens debugging my code. When I use OpenCV by importing cv2 I get the following output:

```
pydev debugger: process 8272 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 141.1899)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2358, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1778, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/work/210 Python/6 imagingSource/test.py", line 3, in <module>
import cv2
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_monkey_qt.py", line 71, in patched_import
return original_import(name, *args, **kwargs)

ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
```

So some DLL can not be loaded. I do not get the error when I normally run the file.

I checked the run and debug environments with the os package. They are almost the same, differing only in some additional entries for the pydev debug environment. I think I also checked whether or not a 64bit interpreter is being used by executing sys.maxsize in both environments. They return the same values so I guess they are both the same - 64bit.

So I am without a clue what could be the cause of this issue. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google translate tells me that `Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.` is `The specified procedure could not be found.` Did you check that your PyCharm paths are configured correctly to find your `cv2`?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry for not having translated that part. I can't find any configuration options for PyCharm (or PyDev) in the GUI. All I can seem to do, is set the Interpreter for the current project, set the PYTHONPATH environment variable for the interpreter to find modules, and set the system's PATH for the interpreter to find DLLs it needs to execute the code I ask it to run. I have set all those as best as I think: the OpenCV dlls are on my path, and the cv2 module is in the PYTHONPATH. My files also execute just fine when NOT debugging / using PyDev in PyCharm. Am I overlooking something?